# How to not render whole block in JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there a JSF 2.1 component which lets me conditionally render (or not render) all its content? Something like

```
<h:component rendered="#{user.loggedIn}">

...a bunch of jsf components and HTML code...
...even more HTML code...

</h:component>
```

I am using PrimeFaces 3M4 as this may influence your answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<h:panelGroup>
```

If you set attribute `layout="block"`, you will have a `<div>` tag

Otherwise, you have a `<span>` tag.

Comment: That's it. A div is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

In general most of jsf components support the render attribute (never bumped in some that does not),
container components like `h:panelGrid or h:panelGroup` supports the rendered attribute and if its set to false all its child will be hidden too

Same goes for the primefaces components ,and if not it probably a bug (i think there was an issue with tabview of primefaces)

Here's a link for primefaces user guide, you can find supported attributes of all primefaces components there [User’s Guide for 3.0.M4](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3M4.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your additional information. I already know the very well structured and complete PF manual but could not figure out what the simpliest way to (not) render a block of elements is, respectively what component is the best to accomplish this.