# Conditional rendering of non-JSF components (plain vanilla HTML and template text)

Tags: html, jsf, conditional-rendering

I'm trying to conditionally render a `<tr>` therefore I cannot use `<h:panelGroup>` as it will render to `<span> or <div>`

My current (working) approach is the following:

```
<h:outputFormat rendered="#{negotiator.maySend}">
    <tr> my tr stuff </tr>
</h:outputFormat>
```

This works, but I'm not sure if that's the way to abuse `<h:outputFormat>` - before that I used `<h:outputLabel>` but this was rendered to `<label>` in IE.

I have also read the answers to this question, but as mentioned above, they won't work for me because of the `<tr>`: [How to not render whole block in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398074/how-to-not-render-whole-block-in-jsf)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> *I cannot use `<h:panelGroup>` as it will render to `<span>` or `<div>`*

Apparently you didn't test it carefully. The [`<h:panelGroup>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/panelGroup.html) won't render anything if you don't specify attributes which should end up in the client side, like `layout`, `id`, `styleClass`, etc.

Thus, this should technically perfectly work fine.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{negotiator.maySend}">
    <tr> my tr stuff </tr>
</h:panelGroup>
```

However, better for the main purpose would be to use [`<ui:fragment>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/ui/fragment.html).

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{negotiator.maySend}">
    <tr> my tr stuff </tr>
</ui:fragment>
```

This is by the way also possible with [`<f:verbatim>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/verbatim.html), but this is deprecated since JSF 2.0 as it's designed specifically for usage in JSP.

#### See also:

- [Alternative to ui:fragment in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713468/alternative-to-uifragment-in-jsf/)
- [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-jsf-components)
- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo/)
- [Ajax update/render does not work on a component which has rendered attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790014/ajax-update-render-does-not-work-on-a-component-which-has-rendered-attribute)