# EL expression in c:choose, can't get it working

Tags: jsf, jstl, el

I'm trying something (JSF2) like this:

```
<p>#{projectPageBean.availableMethods}</p>
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${projectPageBean.availableMethods == true}">
    <p>Abc</p>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <p>Xyz</p>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

But this doesn't seem to work, although the EL expression in the top paragraph changes from false to true, the next paragraph always shows Xyz?

I also tried to change the test to:

```
${projectPageBean.availableMethods}
```

But still the same problem!

Comment: Thanks! The fraction is within <h:body>, <ui:composition>, <h:form>, <p:tabView> and finally a <p:tab> tag!

Comment: My answer is also applicable to `<p:tabView>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost: [**JSTL tags runs during view build time, not during view render time**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense).

Your concrete problem suggests that `#{projectPageBean}` is been set during view render time, such as would happen when definied as `<ui:repeat var>`, `<h:dataTable var>`, `<p:tabView var>`, etc. It's thus `null` during view build time.

In that case, you should not be using a view build time tag to conditionally render HTML. You should instead use a view render time component to conditionally render HTML. As first choice, use `<ui:fragment>`:

```
<p>#{projectPageBean.availableMethods}</p>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{projectPageBean.availableMethods}">
    <p>Abc</p>
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not projectPageBean.availableMethods}">
    <p>Xyz</p>
</ui:fragment>
```

By the way, there's in Facelets no need to switch between `#{}` and `${}`. In contrary to JSP, in Facelets the `${}` behaves exactly the same as `#{}`. To avoid potential confusion and maintenance trouble, I recommend to stick to `#{}` all the time.

#### See also:

- [Conditional rendering of non-JSF components (plain vanilla HTML and template text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946985/the-right-way-to-conditional-rendering-of-non-jsf-components/15947948#15947948)

Comment: Sorry, for this somewhat delayed response! Thanks for your explanation and suggestion. This now works!