# <c:if><c:otherwise> does not work, both conditions evaluate like true

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jstl

I am trying to toggle between two different command buttons depending on whether a list contains the given item ID:

```
               <c:if test="#{roomServiceManagerBean.holdinghotelvilla.contains(hotel.hotelvillaId)}">
                    <p:commandButton ajax="true" id="commanddeactivate" update=":roomserviceForm:hoteltable,:roomserviceForm:msgs" actionListener="#{roomServiceManagerBean.deactivateServiceForHotel(hotel.hotelvillaId)}" icon="ui-icon-radio-off" type="submit" value="Remove Service">
                        <f:param name="roomserviceid" value="#{roomServiceManagerBean.roomServiceId}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </c:if>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <p:commandButton id="commandactivate" update=":roomserviceForm:hoteltable,:roomserviceForm:msgs" actionListener="#{roomServiceManagerBean.activateServiceForHotel(hotel.hotelvillaId)}" icon="ui-icon-radio-on" type="submit" value="Provide Service">
                        <f:param name="roomserviceid" value="#{roomServiceManagerBean.roomServiceId}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </c:otherwise>
```

However, it fails and the both buttons appear. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<c:if>` will in this construct fail if `#{hotel}` is not available during view build time but only during view render time (e.g. because it's definied as `<p:dataTable var>`). The `<c:otherwise>` is completely displaced here. It belongs to a `<c:choose><c:when>`. Technically, you should be using `<c:if>` instead with a negation in the `test`. Or, you should be replacing the first `<c:if>` by a `<c:when>` and wrap the whole thing in `<c:choose>`. However that would still fail if `#{hotel}` is not available during view build time.

Just use JSF component's `rendered` attribute instead.

```
<p:commandButton ... rendered="#{roomServiceManagerBean.holdinghotelvilla.contains(hotel.hotelvillaId)}">
    ...
</p:commandButton>
<p:commandButton ... rendered="#{not roomServiceManagerBean.holdinghotelvilla.contains(hotel.hotelvillaId)}">
    ...
</p:commandButton>
```

#### See also:

- [EL expression in c:choose, can't get it working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218423/el-expression-in-cchoose-cant-get-it-working/)
- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. I actually tried the rendered attribute before I switch to if else tag and it worked. however, one of the button actionListener does not fire. Any things I should look out for?

Comment: See points 4 and 5 of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked

Comment: Thank you so much, I followed your recommendation to have change the scope to viewscope.